# getting BufferOverflowException while running the eclipse

Tags: android, android-support-library, facebook-sdk-3.1

I'm using facebook android sdk (API level 8) to develop the FriendPickerSample part(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/). But after executing I'm getting error like,

```
[2014-01-27 16:50:11 - FriendPickerSample] Dx 
trouble writing output: already prepared
[2014-01-27 16:50:11 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: java.nio.BufferOverflowException. Check the Eclipse log for stack trace.
[2014-01-27 16:50:11 - FriendPickerSample] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: java.nio.BufferOverflowException. Check the Eclipse log for stack trace.
```

I already tried 3 steps:

1.Adding the support library.

2.Fixing the issue without downgrading – (By editing the manifest file).

3.By adding one more line to `project.properties` file(`sdk.build.tools=targetSdkVersion`).

Still getting the same error.

Comment: Right click your project → android tools → android support library.

Comment: already done....no improvement!!!

Comment: try to down the version and clean the project

Comment: already did that....I'm using Android 2.2 (API Level 8)